# Create a column and make it default to a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I have a column in my table that is of type bit, and i will be running a script for many many databases that checks if it exists if it does i need to alter is and add a column and default its bit value to 1 as a default

I tried the following but when it created the column it still shows NULL what am i missing?

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ADD [ShippingOption] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `WITH VALUES` to have the new column take the `default` value rather than `NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable]
ADD [ShippingOption] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 1 WITH VALUES;
```

This is not required if your newly added column is marked as `NOT NULL`. In that case the default will be applied automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When a default constraint is applied to a nullable column such as in this case, the default value is applied only on inserts when the column name is excluded from the list.

Normally this does not apply when you create the field. **Edit:** However, as pointed out by Martin, it is possible to get the desired effect by adding `WITH VALUES`.

Comment: It **is** possible. See my answer.

Comment: You are right, that one had slipped past me. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've created the column with the default value. All future inserts will use this default value if unspecified.

You say "it still shows `NULL`". You'll need to update the existing records:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET ShippingOption = 1
WHERE ShippingOption IS NULL;
```

The reason your default didn't apply: your column is still nullable. So on creation, the default wasn't required to be applied.

You could alternatively specify that the column be `NOT NULL` in your `ALTER` statement. This would ensure that your default would be applied without requiring you to issue an `UPDATE`, as well as ensuring that any statement would require a non-NULL value when inserting:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [ShippingOption] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```